# Hierarchical clustering using Average Linkage

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, clustering, distance

Suppose we have the points $2^0$,$2^1$, ...,$2^n$  on $x$-axis. If we are using Euclidian distance, draw a sketch of the hierarchical
clustering tree we would obtain for the average linkage method.

What I've done:

Let $1 < k < n$ and $C_K$ be the $k$-th cluster obtained in hierarchy. We define the following distances:

$d'=d(C_{k-1},2^k) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (2^k - 2^i)}{k}$
si

$d''=d(2^k,2^{k+1}) = 2^k$

$d'=\frac{k2^k-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i}{k}=\frac{k2^k-(2^k-1)}{k}=\frac{(k-1)2^k+1}{k}$

$d'=\frac{(k-1)2^k+1}{k}=\frac{k2^k+1-2^k}{k}<\frac{k2^k}{k}=d''$, $1 < k < n$

Then, the dendrogram will be something like this:[image: dendrogram]
Sorry about the quality of the picture. Is it correct?

Comment: I've added `self study` tag. Did you try to a small real data snippet? - compute it as you show and draw a tree. Then give the data to a cluster analysis program and get the tree; compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  A simple confirmation is just to implement it.  Here is an implementation in R

```
Tree = hclust(DistMatrix, method="average")
plot(Tree)
plot(Tree, hang=-1)
n = 8
Points = 2^(1:n)
Points
[1]   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256

DistMatrix = dist(Points)
Tree = hclust(DistMatrix, method="average")
plot(Tree, hang=-1)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

Comment: Oke, and the proof seems to be correct, right?